# How to add RabbitMQ library to windows phone 8 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, rabbitmq

I'm working on a WP8 project that needs the RabbitMQ library.

Where and how can I add that kind of library to an windows phone 8 project in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone? I can't seem to find any good ones with the NuGet Package Manager in VSE2012.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you gone to the documentation for RabbitMQ and consulted it for how to add it to your project?

Comment: Yes I took a quick look at it but I don't think there is a proper version for windows phone projects :/ –

Comment: which one did you try? you need at add more detail to your question

Comment: I didn't tried anything because I can't find them in the first place.

Comment: I tried to install the RabbitMQ client with NuGet Package Manager Console but it gives me the following message:

Install-Package : Could not install package 'RabbitMQ.Client 3.0.4'. You are trying to install 
this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but 
the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with 
that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Is there anything that works??

Comment: How could a phone app write/read from a queue? What is the actual usecase for that?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: Perhaps a WP8 application client that subscribes to messages from a publisher?